# Public LAMP with a modem and router

Tags: apache2, router, modem

I am using an Apache2 with a PHP and MySQL installed on Ubuntu. What I would like to do is to run the server public, to access it from outside my network.

However, I am having trouble configuring it, since I am using a ZyXEL P660HW-T3 v2 ADSL Modem with an IP 90.xxx.xxx.xxx together with an ASUS RT-N16 Wi-Fi router with the LAN address 192.168.1.1.

Could someone help me to set up the configuration file correctly to make the server public?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your router to forward port 80 from the WAN interface to 192.168.1.1.